# pass ObservableArray to Model dialog params showing RadListView datas has [Object Object]

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular, radlistview

I have passed Observable array to modal dialog params. When opening the modal dialog, i got a value from radlistview has [object Object].

But if i use listview its working fine. Only with radlistview i have to fix this.

**HomeComponent.ts:**

```
 public obsArr: ObservableArray<App>;
    ngOnInit(){
        this.obsArr= this.homeService.getMyApps();
      }

       const options = {
            context: this.obsArr,
            fullscreen: true,
            viewContainerRef: this.vcRef
          };
          this.modal.showModal(FirstComponent, options).then((resource) => {
          });
```

**FirstComponent.ts:** **(Modal dialog)**

```
  public firstAppArr: ObservableArray<App>;

    constructor(private params: ModalDialogParams, private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.firstAppArr= this.params.context;
    }
```

**first_component.html:** **(Modal dialog html)**

```
<RadListView [items]="firstAppArr" itemReorder="true">
    <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
        <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="*,*">
            <StackLayout col="0" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center">
                <Label [text]="item.name" textWrap="true"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout col="1" horizontalAlignment="right" verticalAlignment="center">
                <Label [text]="item.description" textWrap="true"></Label>

            </StackLayout>     
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>      
</RadListView>
```

Comment: if you add `console.log(this.params)` in the `FirstComponent.ts` constructor, what does it return?

Comment: getting like `Param1 { "context" : { "_observers" : { "change" :[ {} ] },  "_array": [....printing array value ...` @EstebanMarin

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you have in `getMyApps`?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are setting `firstAppArr` to an object of `{"_observers":{}, "_array":[]}`, which is not an array which is what you are looking for. What I would suggest doing is changing your `ngOnInit()` to this

```
ngOnInit() {
    // if you are guaranteed context and array
    this.firstAppArr = this.params.context._array;

    // if you aren't guaranteed context or array. this will either be _array or undefined
    this.firstAppArr = this.params && this.params.context. && this.params.context._array;
}
```

to access the array portion of your object.